# Error: Could not resolve 'd1.google.com'

Tags: upgrade

I have been trying to upgrade ubuntu 16.04. But `sudo apt-get update` gives the error

```
Could not resolve 'd1.google.com'
```

and

```
could not resolve in.archive.ubuntu.com.
```

Consequently

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

is also not working. My desktop is gone... what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Open `source.list`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Try replacing `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

`d1.google.com` should be `dl.google.com`.

Comment: hi...thanks for replying. the source.list is blank

Comment: i am having trouble connecting to a server...gedit, vi none of these editors work...so i can't add a server to resolv.conf